# NoReverseMatch Error

Tags: django, django-authentication

I keep getting this error for the django login system. Here is part of my urls.py:

```
     (r'^contractManagement/login', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}),
```

The exact error I am getting:

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    Reverse for ''django.contrib.auth.views.login'' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

I can't understand why i am getting this error. If you need anything else let me know.

Comment: Where is your reverse statement?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You don't show where you are trying to reverse this URL, but it looks like you have double-quoted it. If you're using the `url` tag, note that you don't need quotes around the url name:

```
{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}
```

not

```
{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}
```

Comment: Is this a fault in the tutorial then? As i had just worked it out to be that.

Comment: Yes, this appears to be a flaw in the tutorial in the example at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login

Comment: To summarise, Django 1.4 should not have quotes while 1.5 will need them. More details on the problem in this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358929/url-gives-me-noreversematch-error-while-reverse-returns-the-url-just-fin

Comment: From Django 1.5 and onwards, use of qoutes is a part of syntax. For 1.4 and below no qoutes are required.

Answer (score 19):

You see that `''the.unknown.view''` is reported including too many qoutes.

It is because the **quoted syntax** will be valid in Django 1.5 and higher. For Django 1.3 or 1.4, you should activate the future behavior by this line in the template:

```
{% load url from future %}
```

which is valid also for Django 1.5.

---

Example for Django 1.5+

```
{% url "path.to.some.view" %}
```

Classic syntax for Django <= 1.4.x (without "future" command) is:

```
{% url path.to.some.view %}
```

Comment: Ah, the example template in the [`views.login` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) contains the future url thing, but doesn't mention what it means (I assumed it was something to do with the `extends "base.html"` line, so ignored it, and.. thus ended up on this question!)

Answer (score 6):

I would give your url a name (in order to do that, you need to use the url method)  Also you should add a trailing slash to all your urls, cause the django CommonMiddleware is going to be doing a 302 redirect on all your urls if you don't:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^contractManagement/login/', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='contract_login'),

)
```

Then you can use reverse in your code, or url in your templates, and if you ever decide to change the actual url (ie: changedCotractManagement/login/), as long as the name is the same, your code will still be good.

in code:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
reverse('contract_login')
```

in template:

```
{% url contract_login %}
```

**Edit:** per MrOodles

Comment: To import reverse: `from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse`