# Error NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django, django-1.10

I keep running in to a `NoReverseMatch` error on Django 1.10, while earlier versions have no problems with it.

rendered template:

```
{% extends "loginBase.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Login:</h1>
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="{% url     'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
  {% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
    {% endif %}
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^login/$', views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm}, name='login'),
```

Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NoReverseMatch error, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Use just `{% url 'login' %}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoReverseMatch Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981026/noreversematch-error)

Comment: @be_good_do_good - the answer you've linked to is Django < 1.5, so it's *really* out of date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Django 1.10, [you can no longer reverse URLs using the Python dotted path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#features-removed-in-1-10), e.g. '`django.contrib.auth.views.login`'.

You already have `name='login'` in your URL pattern,

```
url(r'^login/$', views.login, {...}, name='login'),
```

so use that in the url tag:

```
{% url 'login' %}
```